# How can I create a new array (copy) from another array in C#

Tags: arrays, vb.net, binding, types, reference

I declare some two dimensional arrays in VB.net like so:

```
Public TrainingSet_Inputs()() As Double
Public TrainingSet_Outputs()() As Double

Public OriginalData_Inputs()() As Double
Public OriginalData_Outputs()() As Double
```

Then in a sub I create another set of arrays like so:

```
    Dim Inputs()() As Double
    Dim Outputs()() As Double
```

Which I store information into, after which I do the following modification and assignment:

```
    ' store original data
    OriginalData_Inputs = Inputs
    OriginalData_Outputs = Outputs

    TrainingSet_Inputs = normalise(Inputs)
    TrainingSet_Outputs = normalise(Outputs)
```

It would appear the the values in the OriginalData arrays are being modified to match the TrainingSet after the normalisation is carried out. Is this behaviour to be expected from the way my arrays are defined? There is no other code where I assign the OriginalData to the TrainingSet.

EDIT:

I understand now that arrays are reference types and have modified the question title to what I think is a more useful search item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By typing Array1 = Array2 you just set references, you don't copy the values.
Use

```
    Dim OriginalData_Inputs As Double(Inputs.Count-1)()
    For i = 0 To Inputs.Count - 1
        OriginalData_Inputs(i) = Inputs(i).Clone
    Next
```

This actually creates copies of all the arrays instead of just creating references. It should work.

Comment: is .Clone() doing a deep copy? I thought .Clone() does shallow copies, which I am assuming means it doesn't actually create a new copy of the item? Or is it doing a deep copy because its operating on an element of the array rather than the array itself?

Comment: Clone does indeed a shallow copy. I think the reason why it's working here is because you are working with value types in the arrays itself. You have to be careful with reference types and you may need to adapt a deep copy method for these. I'm no expert though.

Answer (score 2):

Array types are [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) not [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).
Variables of reference types store references to their data.

In a very simplified manner I could explain your situation:

Suppose that after the initialization (new) the six arrays have different references values like these:

```
TrainingSet_Inputs       --> has a reference value of 2000
TrainingSet_Outputs      --> has a reference value of 4000
OriginalData_Inputs      --> has a reference value of 6000
OriginalData_Outputs     --> has a reference value of 8000
Inputs                   --> has a reference value of 10000
Outputs                  --> has a reference value of 12000
```

We could imagine these references as 4 bytes in memory that store these fictional values and these fictional values are pointer to the memory location where we store the array actual values.

When you assign

```
 OriginalData_Inputs = Inputs
 OriginalData_Outputs = Outputs
```

you have changed the reference value of the OriginalData arrays. (the previous memory pointed by the older values will be released by the [Garbage Collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) sometime after this call)

```
TrainingSet_Inputs       --> has a reference value of 2000
TrainingSet_Outputs      --> has a reference value of 4000
OriginalData_Inputs      --> has a reference value of 10000 
OriginalData_Outputs     --> has a reference value of 12000
Inputs                   --> has a reference value of 10000
Outputs                  --> has a reference value of 12000
```

Now, what happen next depend on the method `normalise`, but I suppose that this method returns just the same reference to the input arrays and thus your situation becomes

```
TrainingSet_Inputs       --> has a reference value of 10000
TrainingSet_Outputs      --> has a reference value of 12000
OriginalData_Inputs      --> has a reference value of 10000
OriginalData_Outputs     --> has a reference value of 12000
Inputs                   --> has a reference value of 10000
Outputs                  --> has a reference value of 12000
```

All the Inputs array now have the same reference value and so for the Outputs arrays